# i am using indiasms's api with curl to send sms but after sending sms some contacts get sms content trimmed but some them get proper content

Tags: laravel, curl, sms-gateway

I am using IndiaSMS's api with curl to send SMS.

The odd thing is, some contacts get the SMS content truncated and some of them get content correctly.

```php
$url ="https://app.indiasms.com/sendsms/bulksms.php?username=dummy&password=dummy&type=UNICODE&sender=ALERTS&mobile=$customerNumber&message=$replacesMessage";
if( function_exists("curl_init")){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$response = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
}else{
$return_val = file($url);
$response = $return_val[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to use CURL when programming in Laravel. Use `Http` facade instead:

```
$Response = \Http::get('https://app.indiasms.com/sendsms/bulksms.php?username=dummy&password=dummy&type=UNICODE&sender=ALERTS&mobile=$customerNumber&message=$replacesMessage');

dd($Response->body());
```

For comprehensive reference, do check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client#making-requests).